# Displaying information in same form c#

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, communication

The following code is used by me to pass the data from 3 text boxes(in form 2) to a data grid view (in form 1). The data is passed successfully but the only problem I face is that data is passed to a new form of type f1!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Form1 f1 = new Form1();

            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
             f1.dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
             dt1.Columns.Add("MessageID", typeof(string));
             dt1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
              dt1.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(string));


            DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
            dr["MessageID"] = IDtext.Text; ;
            dr["Name"] = nameText.Text;
            dr["Number"] = numberText.Text;
            dt1.Rows.Add(dr);


            f1.Show();



        }
```

So each time I pass information a new window is created and the previous data i sent does not appear in the data grid view!How can i correct this?

Comment: Create a static instance of `f1` for the class and do not create a new instance of `f1` unless it is null. It will automatically bring loaded form to focus.

Comment: How are you launching `Form2`? There is yet another way to achieve what you seek. You can event to `Form1` as well. I will edit my answer to help you with events and make it more standard for you.

Comment: @praty thanx alot!

Comment: Check my answer now

Answer (score 0):

Your refactored code:

```
class Form2
{
    delegate void PassDataDelegate(DataTable dt1);
    public event PassDataDelegate PassData;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Columns.Add("MessageID", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(string));

        DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
        dr["MessageID"] = IDtext.Text; ;
        dr["Name"] = nameText.Text;
        dr["Number"] = numberText.Text;
        dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

        // This is where you call your event
        PassData(dt1);
     }
}

class Form1
{
    // Your existing Form1 class definition

    private static void YourMethodWhereYouLaunchForm2()
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();

        // Add this handler and you will get it invoked whenever you ask from Form2
        f2.PassData += Handle_DataPassed;
    }

    private void Handle_DataPassed(DataTable dt1)
    {
        // This is where you post the data now to the grid.
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for the answer but i get a red underlined in the "Handle_DataPassed" in the f2.PassData += Handle_DataPassed; section! How can i correct it?

Comment: Did you create the method `private void Handle_DataPassed(DataTable dt1)` ?

Comment: @KushanPeiris: Please always tell the exact error message you get. "red underline" can mean basically anything.

Comment: @paty! An object reference is required for the non static field,method or property is the error i get

Comment: Make `private static void Handle_DataPassed`. Just add `static`

Comment: @praty thanx! when i put static again same error message occurs for data grid view2 in the Handle_DataPassed() method

Comment: well then you can remove static from both the method signatures